# How to display multiple tests with Qunit

Tags: javascript, qunit

The code below has two functions being tested. The contents of these two functions is completely irrelevant. Below these two functions are two additional **test** functions of which each is testing one of the two previous functions.

**The problem**

The only output I get in the Qunit display is the results of the first test function which in this case is "add function". I would like to see both and any additional tests in the same output.
Am I missing some syntax that tells Qunit that I want to see the test results of both?

Thank you.

**Code**

```
function add(a,b){
    return a+b;
};

var answer = add(2,2);


function mathy(a,b,callback){

    return callback(a,b)
}

var mathFunc = mathy(2,2,add)



// Test one

test( "add function", function() {
       ok(answer === 4);

});


// Test2


test( "callback function", function() {

       ok(mathFunc === 4)
});
```

Comment: If anyone has this problem the answer is to simple add:  module( "name-of-module" );       above each test

Answer (score 0):

Use the Qunit `autostart` flag and the `init()` and `start()` methods to run the tests manually:

```
function add(a,b){
    return a+b;
};

var answer = add(2,2);


function mathy(a,b,callback){

    return callback(a,b)
}

var mathFunc = mathy(2,2,add)

QUnit.config.autostart = false;
QUnit.init();
QUnit.start();


// Test one

test( "add function", function() {
       ok(answer === 4);

});


// Test2


test( "callback function", function() {

       ok(mathFunc === 4)
});
```

**References**

- [Managing QUnit Test Suites with Async Module Dependencies | Ian Chan's Blog](https://chanian.com/2011/05/10/managing-qunit-test-suites-with-async-module-dependencies/)
- [Testing Oracle JET Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet112/jet/developer/GUID-CB3225BB-CC3A-4DCE-8772-33EDB55E0BFF.htm#JETDG474)